# Azure CDN - Scripts dont work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've got files stored in my cdn fine, however some scripts and css fail to execute
For example

```
<HTML>
....
</HTML>
<script src="//azxxxx.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(".datetime").datetimepicker({ autoclose: true, pickTime: false, todayHighlight:true }); <--Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
</script>
```

However if I specify the file locally and not use the cdn it works fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the HTML in your example is invalid - you need to define the `<script>` tags within the `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

Secondly, if you are running this locally you *have* to provide the protocol, otherwise `file://` will be used and you'll get browser security blocking file access.

Thirdly, you still need to include jQuery in the page.

Lastly, you need to put your jQuery code in a DOMReady handler.

That being said, try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://azxxxx.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(".datetime").datetimepicker({ 
                    autoclose: true, 
                    pickTime: false, 
                    todayHighlight: true 
                });
             });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- The rest of your markup -->
    </body>
</html>
```

One final note, the link you have to `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` is dead. I would suggest you download a copy of whatever plugin that is and host it locally.

Comment: I thought for performance reason it was best to load script files at the end? https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html

Comment: Either is acceptable. It depends on your situation and the work being done in the script.